# Actuator metrics data when multiple Applications (Spring Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have four services running at

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ => Service1
http://127.0.0.1:9090/ => Service2
http://127.0.0.1:6060/ => Service3
http://127.0.0.1:5050/ => Service4
```

And corresponding Actuator are running at urls :

```
http://127.0.0.1:1234/metrics => Service1 Actuator Metrices
http://127.0.0.1:1235/metrics => Service2 Actuator Metrices
http://127.0.0.1:1236/metrics => Service3 Actuator Metrices
http://127.0.0.1:1237/metrics => Service4 Actuator Metrices
```

Now my doubt is that the information I get from actuator is dependent on other services? I mean lets take the example of GC info.

The info I get for **Service1** Actuator is actually related to **Service1** or is it System GC information which takes into account the GC information for all services.

I mean since all the Services are running on same server so it must be using same JVM? or does JVM internally keeps data separate for all the process(services) in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Some of the information you get from `/metrics` is related only to you application and to be specific it is HTTP metrics. But /metrics also gives you system information which may have included data for other services, since it is system data. Here is more detail about it
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics

Comment: What do you mean by "Some of the information"? Can you be more specific?